# Setting week number of year for Android Time Object

Tags: android, time, calendar, week-number

Is there any possibility to set the week number of the year (1-53) for a android.text.format.Time Object ?

I didn't find any, so would I have to use the java.util.Calendar class instead? Isn't it better to take Time because of performance reasons when doing complex calculations?

Comment: I've been getting ripped off!!! I only get ~52.2 weeks a year! I'm going to have a serious word with god about this *shakes fist*

Comment: Yes, calendar operations are complex.. I had to use the Calendar class instead of Time, as that only provides a getter for weeks. And I had to correct my question, 53 weeks are the max...